# Restricting file download access for all except from a specific domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, download, restriction

I have my Wordpress website on **sample.com** on which I sell my files on using woocommerce.
to host the files (they're big) I have bought a download host which doesn't support database and only serves as file host and is connected to my subdomain  **dl.sample.com**
And files can be downloaded via a button that is accessible by the users who have bought the file.

The problem is, if someone types the file path directly into their browser, they can download it.

**Question:**
Can I somehow restrict the .zip download file from all websites except sample.com so only requests from my main website be allowed to download the .zip files?

P.s: I also used .htaccess file with the following, but didn't work:

```
 <Files something.zip>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from http://sample.com
</Files>
```

p.s 2: I used woocommerce settings to restrict it only to members who buy the file and it uses an altered URL which is pretty secure for me... but the problem is, the download doesn't show Filesize (Only downloaded) and doesn't have a resume button.

Comment: The attempt you show above is invalid, you will see corresponding entries in your http server's error log file. The argument to a "allow from" directive is an IP address, not a URL. Those are different things. Please consult the documentation to learn the details.

Comment: What you ask is not possible in a robust manner. That is not how the web works. If you publish things then you have published them. You cannot publish things generally but then try to prevent that people access what you published. You'd need to implement a session handling to get a robust solution for this. The only thing you could attempt is to evaluate the http referrer header using the apache rewriting module. Again see the documentation for that. But since anyone can arbitrarily change that header such an approach is not robust.